# All executions of callback method hold the same value for an incremented variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer

I currently have a working scheduled callback method using setInterval(), however, an earlier version of my code had really bugged me. It would be great if someone can explain it to me.

This is the full implementation I used earlier that didn't work:

```js
function myCallBack(localPage) {
 console.log('myCallBack ' + localPage);
}

var page = 1;
var timeout = 5000;
var timeoutInterval = 5000
console.log('timeout ' + timeout);
while (page < 10) {
 setTimeout(function() { myCallBack(page) },timeout);
        // Add 10 seconds for the next execution
 timeout += timeoutInterval;
 page++;
}
```

My JavaScript is a little rusty so bear with me if the implementation looks idiotic for something that may seem obvious. Plus I'm not familiar with this setTimeout function and the docs isn't clear to me.

My issue here is that localPage is always 10. Does it pass this value by reference? When I output "page" inside the loop, the numbers are correct. Am I correct in assuming that the callbacks are called after the entire loop executes? The asynchronous behavior is fine by me. I just want each execution to have an earlier value of "page".

To get the script to work, I replaced the entire loop with setInterval().

> Update: zhangjinzhou explains the issue. The callbacks, being
>   non-blocking, is passed through the loop. By the time they all start
>   executing, the last value of "page" is being read by them.
>
> Bougarfaoui's code fixes the issue. Go for Denny's code if you're more of a stickler for syntax.

I guess I was right about this being stupid. When I glanced upon the documentation again:

> Schedules execution of a one-time callback **after** delay milliseconds.
>   Returns a Timeout for use with clearTimeout().

Says AFTER the timeout. So i guess it's safe to say the loop was already done before the timeout completed. Doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that the anonymous function is created in the same scope as the page variable. So by the time the setTimeout fires, the function will reference the future value of page, which will have incremented to 10.

Instead, you can pass the current value of page as an argument to setTimeout directly which will, in turn, pass it to the function you want to fire in the future, like this:

```
function myCallBack(localPage) {
   console.log('myCallBack ' + localPage);
}

var page = 1;
var timeout = 5000;
var timeoutInterval = 5000
console.log('timeout ' + timeout);
while (page < 10) {
    setTimeout(myCallBack,timeout,page);
    // Add 10 seconds for the next execution
    timeout += timeoutInterval;
    page++;
}
```

Comment: This won't work since setTimeout expects a reference to a callback not the result of a callback.

Comment: yep. typo'd my code. passing the myCallback directly, not the result. It's fixed in the example now.

Comment: Hey. This is also a better example! It takes full advantage of the setTimeout api.

Comment: This is actually similar to Python or Java's thread syntax of passing variables to a local thread  variable.

Comment: Setting the question's answer to this since it both explains the issue and the correct usage. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

this solves the problem :

```
var page = 1;
    var timeout = 1000;
    var timeoutInterval = 500
    console.log('timeout ' + timeout);
    while (page < 10) {
        (function(page){
            setTimeout(function() { myCallBack(page) },timeout);
        })(page);

            // Add 10 seconds for the next execution
        timeout += timeoutInterval;
        page++;
    }
```

you have a closure problem , the setTimeout is asynchronous so it will take the last value of page which is 10.

Comment: You're right. Your code fixes my code. This, along with zhangjinzhou's explanation, clarifies things.

Comment: Just for fun I ran both our codes in the same script and they do exhibit the same asynchronous behavior. Only yours just reports the right page number.

Comment: Ey, can you elaborate more on what you mean it's a "closure problem"? And why your approach "works"?

Comment: What I mean by closure problem is that the setTimeout does not remember the current  `page` variable because each iteration it will be incremented so you have to use closures which are features that let you remember the values of variables using functions, for more information see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Comment: Aha! I thought it was a JavaScript thing. Haven't touched the pure stuff for a decade. A little jQuery here an there on occasion and that was it. Plus I usually support legacy apps in IE. So I wouldn't know how much has changed. Thanks again.

Comment: Check out Patrick Denny's solution. It actually takes full advantage of the setTimeout's API by using the variable args parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting 10 every time is asynchronous. If you insert `console.log(page)` before while loop you can see the magic. The program first run 9 times of page++ and set the page to 10. Then it runs callback function for 10 times.

Comment: This actually helps explain it all. Thanks!

Comment: I am glad it helps